# How to create list in root web for every site collection via powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need powershell script to create a custom list named **'test' with Title, URL and an boolean field** in the rootweb of every site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I have tested it

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
    [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges({ 
    $webApplicationURL = "http://xyz:4444/"
    $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $webApplicationURL

    if($webApp -ne $null)
    {
      Write-Host "Web Application : " + $webApp.Name

       foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
        { 
         if($siteColl -ne $null)
          {


             Write-Host "Site Collection : " + $siteColl.Url
             $subWeb = $siteColl.RootWeb;
              write-host $subWeb
                if($subWeb -ne $null)
                  {



                   $spTemplate = $subWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"]
                    $spListCollection=$subWeb.Lists
                     write-host $spListCollection

                    $spListCollection.Add("test","test",$spTemplate)
                    $path =  $subWeb.url.trim()

                    $spList = $subWeb.GetList("$path/Lists/test")
                    $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
                    $spList.Fields.Add("Title",$spFieldType,$false)

                    $spList.Fields.Add("URL","URL",$false)

                     $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Boolean
                    $spList.Fields.Add("Boolean",$spFieldType,$false)


                    $Views = $spList.Views["All Items"]
                    $Views.ViewFields.Add("Title")
                    $Views.ViewFields.Add("URL")
                    $Views.ViewFields.Add("Boolean")
                    $views.Update()



                     $subWeb.Dispose()
                  }
               else
                  {
                    Echo $subWeb "does not exist"
                  }

                $siteColl.Dispose()

          }
     } 
     }


 else
      {       Echo $webApplicationURL "does not exist, check the WebApplication name"
      }Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Echo Finish
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. 
I have not tested it

```
$url = "http://yoursitecollection.com"
 try
 {
     $Site=Get-SPSite $url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
     $spWebApp = $Site.WebApplication
       
     foreach($spSite in $spWebApp.Sites)
     {
        $spWeb = $spSite.RootWeb
        $spTemplate = $spWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"]
        $spListCollection=$spWeb.Lists

        #adding the new list to the list collection
        $spListCollection.Add("test","test",$spTemplate)


        #get the list to the list object 
        $spList = $spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("test")

        if($spList -ne $null)
        {
           #adding the field type(url) to the list 
           $spList.Fields.Add("WebLink","URL",$false)

           $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Boolean
           $spList.Fields.Add("BooleanColumnName",$spFieldType,$false)
           $spList.Update()
        }
        else
        {
            write-host -f yellow "test does not exist in the site"
        }
    }
 }
 catch
 {
     write-host "Unable to Extract Sitecollection List..." -foregroundcolor red
     break
 }
```

Comment: can we check if the list with name 'test' already exists?

Comment: Yes. With TryGetList method. I put in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the PowerShell code. Note that I have not tested it.

```
$contentWebAppServices = (Get-SPFarm).services |
? {$_.typename -eq "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application"}

foreach($webApp in $contentWebAppServices.WebApplications)
{
    Write-Host "Web Application  : " $webApp.name    
    foreach($siteColl in $webApp.Sites)
    {
        // Create a list
        $ListName = "List Name"
        $ListDescription = "List Description"       
        $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $siteColl.Url
        $ListTemplate = $SPWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"]
        $listId = $SPWeb.Lists.Add($ListName, $ListDescription, $listTemplate)

        // Add field
        $spList = $web.Lists[$listId]
        $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Boolean
        $spList.Fields.Add("ColumnName",$spFieldType,$false)
        $spList.Update()
    }
}
```